# selectBox filter in the blade, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to add sorting system by select box in the blade. I made a price sorting by select but couldn't manage to filter by region.

```
<form>
  {{csrf_field()}}
    <select name="sortbyprice">
        <option selected>販売価格</option>
        <option value="asc">最低価格</option>
        <option value="desc">最大価格</option>
    </select>
    <select name="region">
        <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
        <option value="osaka">Osaka</option>
        <option value="kobe">Kobe</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">検索</button>
</form>
```

Sort by price working, but filter "region" is not working. when I select city and push the button. It doesn't bring me matched results. I think in the controller, Region query part I did some mistake.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->q;
    $sortbyprice = $request->sortbyprice;
    $region = $request->region;

    $paginationData = [
        'q' => $q
    ];

    $estates = \DB::table('allestates')
        ->where('lat', '!=', '')
        ->where('lng', '!=', '')
        ->where('price', '!=', '')
        ->where(function($query) use ($q) {
            $query->where("building_name", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("address", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("company_name", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")
                ->orWhere("region", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%");
        })
        ->when($sortbyprice, function($query, $order) use ($paginationData) {
            if(!in_array($order, ['asc','desc'])) {
                $order = 'asc';
            }

            $paginationData['sortbyprice'] = $order;

            return $query->orderBy('price', $order);

        }, function($query) {
            return $query->orderBy('price');
        })
        ->when($region, function($query, $regionId) use ($paginationData) {
            $paginationData['region'] = $regionId;
            return $query->where('region_id', $regionId);
        })
        ->paginate(8);

    $paginationData = array_filter($paginationData);

    return view("home", compact('estates', 'q','paginationData'));
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your html to have the `asc` or `desc` values in the dropdown.

```
<select name="sortbyprice">
    <option value="asc">Lowest First</option>
    <option value="desc">Highest First</option>
</select>
<select name="region">
    <option value="tokyo">Tokyo</option>
    <option value="osaka">Osaka</option>
    <option value="kobe">Kobe</option>
</select>
<input name="q" type="button">
```

In your controller you also need to `use (&$paginationData)` [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) instead of value or the values will not persist after you run your callback.

Comment: I used the select box like u suggest and hit the button but it's not running and no errors also. Is my controller wrong or... by the way I don't understand the this part `use (&$paginationData)`

Comment: Can you post some more code like what is triggering the controller to run? How are you showing the list of results? Also by reference means you can change the values. Passing by value means you can use the variable but if you change anything it won't be saved after the function is done running.

Comment: thank you for replying me back. I updated the question. First, I can do sortbyprice now. asc and desc. But my region sort is not working. I think some mistakes in the region query. Because I choose the city it doesn't bring me that city results.

Comment: Ok, what do you want the results to look like? It doesn't look like you are sorting by region, you are just filtering by region - which at the top you are searching by 'region' and at the bottom you are searching by 'region_id'. Are there separate columns like that in the DB?

Comment: Acutally, I have two options. you can search it, or select it with the select box. I mean, I have search box, and you can write there, for example tokyo. and it checks the region row in the DB, fetches those. But also I want to make a select box too. select a tokyo and fetch it. Like you said, I am tying to filter I guess...

Comment: in the region query. I try to use same filter like I did in the searchbox. But this time not search directly select the name.

Comment: So...what do you actually want to happen??

Comment: I think I can't explain it very well :) try to filter region row's data with select box. when I select osaka, it bring me just osaka not the other cities... I doing it in the search box like this:`orWhere("region", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%");`  but in the region query below. I can't managed it.

Comment: Did you try changing to `where('region', $regionId)`? Instead of region_id

Comment: yes, I did. no effects. can I use this `where("region", "LIKE", "%" . $q . "%")` I tried but couldn't make it.

Comment: Can you show some example data of the table you are searching?

Comment: for example. I search tokyo in the search box in give me one result without problem. https://imgur.com/a/kTt8Akc and then I try to seach osaka and give me more results. https://imgur.com/a/KYwvzbI I try to make that in selectBox version.

Comment: You said that already, I mean can you post actual data, in a table format?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand what u asking. I don't have table format. https://imgur.com/a/yenaXhP or this? https://imgur.com/a/n84MkQy

Comment: Table format meaning, the column names and some examples of rows in the database

Comment: region is row name. And i did value="" what inside that column for example: 関東or関西

Comment: the actual problem is in this query `->when($region, function($query, $regionId) use ($paginationData) {
            $paginationData['region'] = $regionId;
            return $query->where('region_id', $regionId);
        })`

Comment: Yeah cause you need to search by the column 'region' not 'region_id'